# Bulk Change Wordpress category Slug

Tags: categories, mysql, terms, sql

Am trying to bulk add "subbed" at the end of 5k category terms. I tried running this in sql.

```
update wpkf_terms
set cat_name = CONCAT(cat_name, '-subbed')
```

But I got this error

```
Error
SQL query:


update wpkf_terms
set cat_name = CONCAT(cat_name, '-subbed')
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'cat_name' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 0):

wpkf_terms do not contain field called **cat_name**. Try using below query.

```
update wpkf_terms set name=CONCAT(name, '-subbed') Where term_id IN (SELECT term_id from wpkf_term_taxonomy where taxonomy='category')
```